# How can I Stop receiving notifications from someone without opening theirs chat( Google Chat )

Tags: google-hangouts, google-hangouts-chat, google-chat

My Company uses Google Chat(G Suite) as an IM client.
I'm having trouble and don't want to receive chat notifications from a specific person.

I want to clear the "Notifications" checkbox in the attached image
[image: http://wcblitzy.blogspot.com/2015/07/86-hangouts-how-to-turn-off-chat.html]

So I referred to the official help.
However, it seems that I can't change the notification settings until I open a chat with the person.

https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3111919?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en-GB

> 1. Go to Hangouts at hangouts.google.com or in Gmail.
> 2. Click a contact or conversation.
> 3. Click Settings.
> 4. Untick Notifications.

As you know, Google Chat has "Read receipts".
Once I open a chat, the opening notification will be shared with the person.

https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2020/09/coming-soon-see-read-receipts-on-direct.html

I am in a position to refuse any contact with the person,
so I don't even want to know what I've read.

I just want to avoid opening chats and getting notifications from him, but is there any way?

Comment: @LWC I'm no sure that [tag:google-hangouts] should be removed as the images shown in the question correspondes to [tag:google-hangouts] not to [tag:google-chat] (formerly named [tag:google-hangouts-chat])

Answer (score 0):

Google Chat web app has a panel showing the recent 1:1 conversations. To turn off the notifications for one of this conversations, click the three dot menu, then **Turn of notifications**.